# Why do certain phrases like "para que" and "sin que" trigger the subjunctive?

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

I remember learning ESCAPA A in Spanish class and having to memorize each of these subjunctive triggers, but I am just curious from a technical/grammatical standpoint *why* this occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El subjuntivo puede expresar un deseo, intención o propósito. Suele usarse generalmente en frases subordinadas que comienzan con "que" o aparece un "que", "para que", "sin que"..., aunque en algunos casos aparecen inducido por algún elemento gramatical en frases que expresan duda o falta de seguridad en la afirmación que se realiza a continuación. Así, será el fondo del asunto que encierra un deseo, una posibilidad, probabilidad, irrealidad, etc, el que va a imponer que el verbo que aparezca tenga que utilizarse en modo subjuntivo.

*Ejemplos*

- No creo *que* hable con ella hasta mañana. (posibilidad)
- Es probable *que* disfrutes esa película. (probabilidad)
- No me parece *que* esa sea la mejor opción. (probabilidad)
- Roberto nos pidió *que* trajéramos más turrón. (deseo)
- ¡Dudo *que* pueda aprenderlo todo en una sola sesión! (irrealidad)